# Strange fgets() problem

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to run this code on Windows 7 (64-bit, if it matters) after compiling it with GCC. If I declare bufsize as an int, the program freezes and Windows informs me that it's stopped working. If I use 
    #define bufsize 123 
it works fine, and it works fine if I replace bufsize with a number myself. What am I missing here?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char* filename = argv[1];

    FILE* problem = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!problem) {
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* line;
    while (fgets(line, bufsize, problem) != NULL) {        
        printf(line);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The biggest conceptual mistake that nobody is pointing out to you is that you don't need a `bufsize` variable. You must pass the buffer size to `fgets`, but this is most often done as `sizeof buffer` or some other expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` is a pointer, but it is pointing nowhere (or, better, it hasn't been initialized and its value is indeterminate and unusable). A pointer that points nowhere isn't terribly useful.

Allocate some memory and make `line` point to that memory. Remember to deallocate memory when you no longer need it.

```
line = malloc(200);
if (line == NULL) { /* something went wrong, the pointer is pointing nowhere */ }
/* ... use allocated memory ... */
free(line);
```

Oh ... and `bufsize` value should match the number of bytes you allocated.

Also `#include <stdlib.h>` because `malloc()` and `free()` have their prototype there.

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated space for the buffer pointed to by `line`.

You should do:

```
line = malloc(bufsize);
```

and free it using:

```
free(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

`bufsize` is the size of the buffer that you are supposed to allocate and pass to `fgets`. You haven't allocated any buffer at all, and then you are lying to `fgets` telling it that you are passing a buffer of some specific size. It does not matter what size you are using or how you pass it to `fgets` - as long as you are not allocating any buffer, your code will crash or behave unpredictably.

As long as the buffer size is not very large, you can declare it as a local array, instead of allocating it dynamically

```
char line[bufsize];
while (fgets(line, bufsize, problem) != NULL) {        
    printf(line);
}
```

Comment: Just thought I'd mention this (the VLA) works for `C99`, which the OP is already using (mixed code and declarations).

Answer (score 0):

```
char* line = malloc(bufsize);
```